# How to log errors with Firebase Hosting for a deployed Angular web app

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am working on an Angular single page web app which uses Firestore as the database and will be deployed to Firebase Hosting. There seems to be no built-in way to log errors to the server or get run-time analytics unless you are developing an Android or iOS mobile app. I want to be able to view the web log files and find out about errors or abuse and see other typical live usage data.

For example if the database code throws an error or a web API call returns an unexpected value and I catch the error. I can console.log the problem when developing and testing in Chrome, but what about for a production website? What is the best practice for logging within a SPA when hosting on Firebase? Is the only option to manually add records to the database or is there another way I am not familiar with to write to a server log file? Thanks for your advice on logging best practices with Firebase hosting an Angular web app.

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics doesn't support Web. You can manage your own error handling or check out a service like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/).

Comment: Yes at present Crashlytics doesn't support web. Maybe it will in the future. Thank you for the recommendation of Sentry. Is there a list of error handling and crash reporting open source tools that are recommended and compatible with Firebase Hosting and Angular?

Comment: chatGPT thought it supported web too dam it .

Answer (score 2):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Please have a look into this.

It seems that your `console.log` errors is enough for firebase

### EDIT

well writing logs comes with certain cost and quota policy for firebase.
You can create a cloud function just to write the logs that you incur in the angular side.

You can call an api service from the angular project that writes into the only cloud function in your app and then you can see those in the logs view under firebase functions.

But please note that it may come under some cost.

Comment: Yes for Firebase Functions, logging to the console works very well. Unfortunately for an Angular SPA, there is no way to write to the server console from the client browser. When a user error happens in Angular Typescript (Javascript) on the browser (web app), how can I send a log entry to the Firebase Hosting server? That is the question. Thanks.

Comment: I have tweaked my answer a bit, I don't whether this is something you wanted, but still hope it works.

Comment: Perhaps this is the only reasonable answer until Firebase offers StackDriver Logging or a similar built-in feature for Angular. I agree it can get very expensive to call a Firebase Function to log events, but maybe only for critical errors.

Comment: Has anyone done this in an Angular web app and can offer real-world advice? Like how best to define the logging function and call it to make log entries in Firebase Functions. Thanks!

Comment: Just like I said, you could write a service file in angular and call it whenever there is a critical error that you want to log into firebase.
In this service you call the cloud function that simply logs the error.

But of course this is costly and you may need to consider the quota policy for this. And I don't think it may exceed the monthly quota if you don't have quite a lot of errors.
Also you may need to consider other solutions as well

Answer (score 2):

for anyone still looking for the answer,
From 11-08-2020, there is a new feature for getting all the logs for your firebase hosting project, more about it in official documentation [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics)

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks for contributing this important new feature. This is one more step towards making Firebase Hosting a full-featured solution. Question: Can I use an API call to send data to the Cloud Logging for a hosted web app? Need to read the specs. For an Angular web app want to make cloud.console.log calls if possible.

Comment: There is no client side sdk to send log from the browser. Too bad, at first I thought it was what I was looking for.